# How to Reliably Track Human Page Views on my article Pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ads, counter

I have searched online for this and came across an article that suggested I should use an image to track human page views because search engine and bots don't download images. It said I should put the image code in javascript like: document.write('code here'). The system I am developing heavily depends on accurate unique user visits the the page. This will be the life blood of the site so i am really worried about someone trying creating a script to read the image file a million times to fraud the page count. Is this the best way to do this?

Comment: Then how did Google Images come about?

Comment: I don't think it's ever possible to RELIABLY track human page views. I could go write a shell script right now and use wget or curl or something to access your pages - how would you ever know?

Answer (score 2):

Heat Maps are a great solution that can be easily integrated into your site from 3rd parties.

```
http://www.labsmedia.com/clickheat/index.html
http://www.clickdensity.com/
```

Using this along with Google Analytics and you've got a full solution.

Comment: Would I be able to see the exact count of each article page. I estimate about 1 million pages.

Comment: Wow, cool stuff. I just installed the labsmedia kit on my site. That took all of like 3 minutes. Easy!

Comment: Luke, for a site with such a large footprint Google Analytics is perhaps the leader in the game.  You would be able to see exact counts with it.  The heat maps are great for understanding how people are using your site more than anything.

Comment: Analytics really is the way forward until you have a packet to spend on something like tealeaf.